# Is it possible to remove the ability to delete SMS text messages?

Tags: ios, text, sms, block, message

Is there any way, jailbroken or not, to block or remove the ability to delete messages from the "Messaging" app on an iPhone. If not would this be something one would be able to program in an app to remove the option forcefully on a jailbroken phone?

Answer (score 0):

Without modifying iOS, AFAIK, you can't get this functionality, and why would you want to do this in the first place?

Answer (score 0):

Not jailbroken: no

Jailbroken: yes using mobile substrate this could be made possible.